# How i can update single filed of array in state in redux?

Tags: redux

I need update one field in a state => books => (one indicated book) => (one of book field).

I try do this that

```
export default function(state = initialState, action){
case EDIT_BOOK:
            return {
                ...state,
                books :{
                    ...state.books,
                    title: action.title
                }
            }
```

My state looks like

```
books:[
  {
    "_id": "5cfa9698361a8427b85dc79f",
    "title": "Krzyżacy",
    "author": "Henryk Sienkiewicz",
    "__v": 0,
    "state": "toReads"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5cfa9bd1cb5c152ee4269a28",
    "title": "Quo Vadis",
    "author": "Henryk Sienkiewicz",
    "state": "toReads",
    "__v": 0
  }
]

//Action

export const editBook = (id, title) => dispatch => {
   axios
        .put(`http://localhost:5000/books/${id}`, title)
        .then(res => dispatch({
            type: EDIT_BOOK,
            payload: id,
            newTitle: title
        }))
```

My second problem is thus

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/books/5cfa9698361a8427b85dc79f' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: I try this
`router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    const newBook = new Book({
        title: req.body.book.title,
        author: req.body.book.author,
        state: "toReads"
    });`
But doesnt work

Comment: Funny in method get it works, but in post nope

`router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    Book.find()
    .sort({ date:-1 })
    .then(items => {res.json(items); res.status(200)})
    .catch(err => req.err)
});


// 
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    req.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
 
    const newBook = new Book({
        title: req.body.title,
        author: req.body.author,
        state: "toReads"
    });
});`

Answer (score 0):

You are updating array incorrectly. See this pattern from redux documentation:
https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array

Be carefull and do not change your books from array into object (use output of function updateObjectInArray from above link and put it into your books property)

```js
case EDIT_BOOK:
    return {
        ...state,
        // here you are putting object instead of array into books
        books :{
            ...state.books,
            title: action.title
        }
    }
```

Solution for your second problem is using e.g. nginx in your local development environment for passing requests to your frontend application and backend api to the right address/port.
Nginx configuration will look something like this (simplified, just for giving a right direction):

```
server {
   # port where nginx will run (you will debug your web application on this port from now)
    listen       8081;

    location / {
       # address of your frontend application (e.g. webpack dev server)
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
    location /backend {
       # address of your backennd application
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
}
```

As I wrote above, after that configuration you need to debug application on nginx proxy and not on frontend server (e.g. webpack dev server), but the server should be still running. The nginx proxy application url according to the above configuration will be: http://localhost:8081
And whenever your application would like to call backend api, it will do it this way:

```
// your old address will change into ...
http://localhost:5000/books/${id}

// ... this new address
/backend/books/${id}
```